# MS-DOS copy from the visual studio external tools

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2008

I'm trying to execute the **copy** command from the visual studio external tools, but I'm getting an error saying that the command is unknown.

How should i set the path for the copy command? as i know it's operation system command and not executable file.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `copy` command is a built-in, not an external program.  You could use `cmd.exe /c copy (args)` to execute it. Alternately, `xcopy` is an external program (`xcopy.exe`).